# Only part one part of the model is being rendered

Tags: rendering

I’m trying to do is a very simple animation: a mesh, a moving 3D–animation of a mouth. It has two layers: one is the lips (red), the other is the inside of the mouth which is black. Consequently I have 2 materials under the material slot. Under the mesh slot, I’ve connected the two parts of the mouth as a vertex group. I’ve created 2 shape keys: one for closed and one for open. These values are keyframed and will eventually be baked to a sound file, making the mouth move in sync. Everything looks fine and dandy when I play the animation. But when I tried to render it, all my previous problems seem very light indeed. First I couldn’t render anything at all. Finally I found a post saying and should uncheck the compositing and the sequencer. That made the trick. Almost. Problem is, it only renders the red part of the image. Can someone please help me out. Please?

I'm attaching one image, it seems that it is the limit here? I can supply more if needed[image]

Comment: Hi, can you upload .blend and insert link to question? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I uploaded the file via the link you supplied. I hope it worked.

Comment: It didn't, you have to give us a link otherwise we can't download anything

Comment: Ok. Bear with me I'll try to figure out what doing wrong

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3879" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3879/)

Comment: That's the way to do it, right?

Answer (score 1):

All what you need to do is move black part a little bit higher, because you have two faces on exact same level - overlaped. Blender can't know which one is on top.

Anyway: I recommend you search for some tutorials about topology and animations.

Comment: Ok. So I’ve deleted the extra layer. But it doesn’t solve the problem. When I render, the black part is only partially rendered. And when I tick shadeless (which is what I want) in the material slot, only the red is rendered. Is it really the "topology" or might it be the black mesh that is somehow faulty?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3881" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3881/)

Comment: Sorry, Shubol3D,  I read your reply without really understanding it. I'm not how to to what you propose but I'll look into "topology" and see if I can figure it out

Comment: I think I finally grasped it and really seems to be working (I just lifted the black part on the y–axis just as you told me). It makes sense that you can’t put things in one plane in a 3D–environment. Thank you ever so much for helping out in my hour of need.

Have you, by the way, ever seen the Python sketch about “ The Royal Society for Putting Things on top of other things ...”. Well, maybe we need one after all ;–)